# SVG curved text inside path

Tags: html, css, svg

Hello guys I created a circle with 5 segments with SVG, im trying to add text inside the segments but I can't get it to work right.

This is what Im trying to do
[Text curved and centered inside the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lOtn.png)

this is what im getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW0Ko.png)

This is my code so far, any suggestions?

```
<svg  viewBox='0 0 110 110' style="margin-top: 10px;transform: rotate(18deg);">
   <a xlink:href="">
      <path  class="frag logoa" id="f1" data-link="1" d='M55,55 L14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318z' >
      </path>
      <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="15" stroke="red";>
         <textPath xlink:href="#f1">
            We go up, then we go down, then up again
         </textPath>
      </text>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="2" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318 A50,50 0 0,1 105,54.999999999999986z' ></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="3" d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768z'></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""  >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="4" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768 A50,50 0 0,1 14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366z' ></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""   >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="5" d='M55,55 L14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366 A50,50 0 0,1 14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635z' ></path>
   </a>
   <circle class="cente" cx='55' cy='55' r='35' ></circle>
   <circle class="minicirculo" cx='55' cy='55' r='15' ></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the font size?

Comment: Yes I've tried that...........

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this or want to use an external library, but this has examples with code similar to what you're trying to do: https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using one of the circle segment paths as the path for your text.  See below.

```css
path, circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox='0 0 110 110' style="margin-top: 10px;transform: rotate(18deg);">
   <a xlink:href="">
      <path  class="frag logoa" id="f1" data-link="1" d='M55,55 L14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318z' >
      </path>
      <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="4" fill="red";>
         <textPath xlink:href="#f1">
            We go up, then we go down, then up again
         </textPath>
      </text>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="2" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318 A50,50 0 0,1 105,54.999999999999986z' ></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="3" d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768z'></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""  >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="4" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768 A50,50 0 0,1 14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366z' ></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""   >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="5" d='M55,55 L14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366 A50,50 0 0,1 14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635z' ></path>
   </a>
   <circle class="cente" cx='55' cy='55' r='35' ></circle>
   <circle class="minicirculo" cx='55' cy='55' r='15' ></circle>
</svg>
```

Obviously you that path is not appropriate. You need to add a new, simpler, path that goes from the left of a segment to the right of the segment.  You'll need to do that for each segment.

Alternatively, you can use a path that forms an entire circle, then re-use that path for each segment. But specifying a different `startOffset` attribute for each, corresponding to their positions around the circle.

In the following example, I create a circular path with a radius of 40.

```
<path id="clockwise" d="M55,15 A40,40 0 0 1 55,95 A40,40 0 0 1 55,15"/>
```

Then I use this same path for each segment.  To make centering the text in each segment easy, I use the attribute `text-anchor="middle"` which will result in the text being centred on the `startOffset` we specify.

We can use percentages to specify how far around our circular path we want the text to start.  0% would be the start of the path (also the left side of the first segment), 20% would be the start of the second segment, etc.

So, for the first segment we want the text to be centred at a point halfway in, so we use `startOffset="10%"`. For subsequent segments, we would use "30%", "50%" etc.

In the example below, I've done the first three segments. I'll leave the last two for you to finish.

To learn more about how `<textPath>` works, [read the relevant section of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-TextPathElement).

```css
path, circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110' style="margin-top: 10px;transform: rotate(18deg);">
   <defs>
     <!-- Circular path with a radius of 40 -->
     <path id="clockwise" d='M55,15 A40,40 0 0 1 55,95 A40,40 0 0 1 55,15'
           transform="rotate(-54,55,55)"/>
   </defs>
   <a xlink:href="">
      <path  class="frag logoa" id="f1" data-link="1" d='M55,55 L14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318z' >
      </path>
      <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="6" fill="red";>
         <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise" startOffset="10%" text-anchor="middle">
            Cloud Marina
         </textPath>
      </text>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="2" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318 A50,50 0 0,1 105,54.999999999999986z' ></path>
      <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="6" fill="red";>
         <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise" startOffset="30%" text-anchor="middle">
            Order This
         </textPath>
      </text>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href="" >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="3" d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768z'></path>
      <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="6" fill="red";>
         <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
            Earn This
         </textPath>
      </text>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""  >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="4" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768 A50,50 0 0,1 14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366z' ></path>
   </a>
   <a xlink:href=""   >
      <path class="frag logoa" data-link="5" d='M55,55 L14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366 A50,50 0 0,1 14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635z' ></path>
   </a>
   <circle class="cente" cx='55' cy='55' r='35' ></circle>
   <circle class="minicirculo" cx='55' cy='55' r='15' ></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks Helped me a lot